# Inserting MS Access Row Into Database using vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, oledbcommand

So im trying to add fields to a database. It is .mdb database, microsoft access.

The Name of the table is Contacts.

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source= C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Contacts.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()

    sql = "INSERT INTO Contacts (FName, LName, Age, Address Line 1, Address Line 2, City, State, Zip, Home Phone, Work Phone, Email, Sex) VALUES (a, b, c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Contacts")
```

My Error is Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. Which makes no sense, whatsoever. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT*
I solvedmy riginal problem by adding [] around certian fields as suggested, thanks. Now I am getting...

No value given for one or more required parameters.

The database has a primary ID field that autoincrements, does this change anything?

Comment: Where are defined the `a, b, c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k`?

Comment: just values im trying to insert to test, they will eventually be whatever value i want to enter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers have already explained you need to use square brackets around column names that contain spaces, but also you need to add a value for the fields otherwise you cannot execute the command.

I will try to show a complete example

```
Dim dbProvider  = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
Dim dbSource = "Data Source= C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Contacts.mdb"

Dim sql = "INSERT INTO Contacts (FName, LName, Age, " & _ 
          "[Address Line 1], [Address Line 2], City, State, Zip, " & _ 
          "[Home Phone], [Work Phone], Email, Sex) " & _
          "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource)
Using cmd = new OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "Value For FName")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", "Value For LName")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Convert.ToInt32("Value For Age"))
    .... and so on for the other parameters .....
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

In this example I have inserted 12 placeholders for the parameters (?) and then added the first  3 parameters out of 12 required. Note that with OleDb the parameter collection still requires to add the parameters with a name (*@pX*), but when executing the query the parameter value is picked following the same order of the placeholder.

Also I have used the Using statement to close and dispose the disposable objects like the connection and the command.

Finally, an Insert query is normally executed using ExecuteNonQuery from the OleDbCommand and there is no need to use an OleDbAdapter and call Fill to load a DataSet when no SELECT query is executed

Comment: Something doesn't connect here, where exactly is the variable `sql` being used?

Comment: he messed up the example

Using cmd = new OleDb.OleDbCommand(commandText, con)

should be sql instead of commandtext, i used the variable sql to hold my sql command

Answer (score 3):

Put column names with spaces between squares brackets []

For example `[Address Line 1]`

Cheers

Comment: So I did this and the new error is

No value given for one or more required parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Tables and fields names composed of a single word can be written directly, such as `FName`.

Names like `Address Line 1` howover will need to be wrapped between `[]` in order to make the synthax consistent.

```
INSERT INTO Contacts (FName, LName, Age, [Address Line 1], [Address Line 2], City, State, Zip, [Home Phone], [Work Phone], Email, Sex) VALUES (...
```

The same applies to objects named with reserved words.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood what your needs are correctly:

> <sub><sub>***Translated from*** : Se entendi o que está precisando é isto aqui,veja o código:</sub></sub>

```
comando = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO TabClientes(NomeCliente,Telefone,CEP,Rua,Bairro,Cidade,Estado)" & _
                                 "Values (@nome,@telefone,@cep,@rua,@bairro,@cidade,@estado)")
        comando.Connection = conn
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txtnome.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", mkbtelefone.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cep", mkbcep.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rua", txtrua.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bairro", txtbairro.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cidade", txtcidade.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", txtestado.Text)
        ' comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If comando.ExecuteNonQuery Then
            MessageBox.Show("Registro salvo com sucesso ...")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao tentar gravar o registro ...")

        End If
        conn.Close()
```