# rows.add access database vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net

I'm building an applications that uses an access database.
I can successfully add a new row, but when i add a second row i get the error:

```
System.Data.ConstraintException occurred in System.Data.dll

Column "Name" is constrained to be unique.  Value "katy" is already present.
```

There is only 1 record in the database with Name value Kevin, so the value katy is not present.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Checkin
Dim checkin As Camping_databaseDataSet.CampingRow
Private Sub Checkin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    arrivalpick.Text = DateAndTime.Now
    checkin = Camping_databaseDataSet.Camping.NewCampingRow()
    CampingTableAdapter.Fill(Camping_databaseDataSet.Camping)
    Camping_databaseDataSet.Camping.NewCampingRow()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnSaveRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSaveRecord.Click
    checkin.ArrivalDate = CDate(arrivalpick.Text)
    checkin.City = txtcity.Text
    If chkconnection.Checked = True Then
        checkin.Connection = True
    Else
        checkin.Connection = False
    End If
    checkin.Country = txtcountry.Text
    checkin.Name = txtname.Text
    checkin.NoAdults = adultcount.Text
    checkin.NoCaravan = caravancount.Text
    checkin.NoChildren = childcount.Text
    checkin.NoDogs = dogcount.Text
    checkin.NoGrey = greycount.Text
    checkin.NoMobilhome = mobilhomecount.Text
    checkin.NoShowercoins = showercoincount.Text
    checkin.NoTent = tentcount.Text
    checkin.NoTransport = transportcount.Text
    checkin.NoYellow = yellowcount.Text
    checkin.Street = txtstreet.Text
    checkin.EndEdit()
    Camping_databaseDataSet.Camping.Rows.Add(checkin)
    Me.CampingTableAdapter.Update(Me.Camping_databaseDataSet)
    Camping_databaseDataSet.Camping.AcceptChanges()
    End Sub
End Class
```

What am i doing wrong?

[image: Gridview]

[image: DB connecyion]

Comment: the error means what it says.  Your db has 'Name' defined as a unique value, so only one row with John or Mary or Jose can exist in that table.

Comment: @Plutonix , that's the thing. There only is 1 row in the table. With name Kevin. There are no other rows.

Comment: make sure you are looking at the same DB that the app is writing to

Comment: @Plutonix I'm sure of that, there only is 1 row in the table. With name Kevin. There are no other rows.

Comment: @Plutonix i've added an image with a grid view, as you can see, there is only one row.
there is one strange thing, if i add a row in the program (when there are no rows in the DB) it works and the row is added in the gridview. but, if i close the program and open the DB file with access, the DB is empty. if i then reopen the program, all the added data is gone to (but if i do not open the DB file with access, the data stays in the DB)

Comment: @kevinsterckx try deploying your database and see if that works (debugging I THINK will only save temprarily

Comment: @jbutler483 i've tried it, and same error

Comment: i'm guessing (somewhere during testing) you've used the name 'Katy' - try finding out where this value has been stored (probably somewhere in the server explorer).

Comment: @jbutler483 , i even get the error when i use something like "test" or "hello" or something else i've never used before

Comment: @kevinsterckx could i see your connection string (edit question to add it)

Comment: @jbutler483 what do you mean?

Comment: what's your connection string?

Comment: @jbutler483 I think i don't have a connection string, i've added the DB to the Data connections, and that's it.

Comment: The code in the question is the entire code for the checkin form

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148532-using-datagridview-with-access/ <-- look at this. It uses purely code to add to a database (probably a better/more robust way of adding data to be honest)

Comment: or even: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21961951/3436942

Comment: that could be a solution (but wil require me to rewrite the whole program, i've got multiple forms in the project)
but wat i find strange, is that i can successfully add 1 row, but if i want to add a second one , i get the error.
is there an other solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the table itself.

I had a column called "name", this was a reserved object in Access.

By changing it, the problem was solved.