# VB.Net SQL Insert into Using Windows Forms Data

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Alright, I have picked up everything I know for VB.Net from trial and error.  I have built an SQL string that works in Access and tried to implement it, however it doesn't seem to work in my program.  I totally accept that I don't have a firm grasp on it, so what am I doing wrong?  This particular form just needs to take the text from textboxes in a Windows form and insert them into a database.

```
    Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO StudentTable VALUES ('" + BadgeNoTextBox.Text + "','" + FirstNameTextBox.Text + "','" + LastNameTextBox.Text + "','" + SAPSIDTextBox.Text + "','" + EmailTextBox.Text + "'.'" + PhoneTextBox.Text + "','" + CollegeComboBox.Text + "')"
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""C:\Users\larsennicholasg\Documents\Visual Studio   2012\Projects\SSCLogin\SSCLogin\My Project\SSCStudent.mdb"""
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(insertSql, conn)

    If (da.Update(ds)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Success")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Fail")
    End If
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As a side note I'd be happy to look into books or a good Vb.net -> sql reference site, I've looked but can't seem to settle on one that is consistent.

Comment: You forgot to execute your query `da.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Have a look at this using parameters instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961951/inserting-ms-access-row-into-database-using-vb-net

Comment: Please expand on "doesn't seem to work"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO StudentTable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""C:\Users\larsennicholasg\Documents\Visual Studio   2012\Projects\SSCLogin\SSCLogin\My Project\SSCStudent.mdb"""
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr), _
      cmd As New OleDbCommand(insertSql, conn)

    ''# I had to guess at types and lengths here. 
    ''# Adjust this to use actual types and lengths in your database
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(BadgeNoTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 20).Value = FirstNameTextBox.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 20).Value = LastNameTextBox.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(SAPSIDTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50).Value = EmailTextBox.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = PhoneTextBox.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 35).Value = CollegeComboBox.Text

    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

The use of query parameters rather than string substitution is important. What you had was crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: The ?'s are variable names?  What are they for?

Comment: They're just placeholders for the query parameters. Some providers use named parameters and match the value to the parameter in the query by name, but OleDb matches up the parameter to placeholder by the order in which they appear in the query and Parameters collection, so you just use a `?`.

Comment: Do I need one for EVERY parameter in the table?  (The first column is an autonumber value)

Comment: No, skip autonumber columns.

Comment: Alright here's the new code, but I'm getting a "Additional information: Number of query values and destination fields are not the same." Error

Comment: Make sure the number of `?` in the sql string matches the number of parameters you add to the command. Because of the autonumber field, you may need to include the field names in the sql string before the values clause.

Comment: Also: don't edit new code into my answer. Edit your changes into the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87813/discussion-between-skathix-and-joel-coehoorn).