# add listbox values to access database windows form application

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a calculator with two textboxes where the user puts a number in each one. They then click a plus, minus, divide, or multiply button and it does that function to the numbers. These numbers are saved to a listbox called listbox1. When the user clicks to display the results, the listbox is populated with all their saved values, and the application is SUPPOSED to save the listbox items to an access database. it is not working. Below is my code, where numFirst is the name of a category in the database table:

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
  btnDisplay.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    For arrayindex As Integer = 0 To intarrayCount - 1

        ListBox1.Items.Add(Input(arrayindex))
        ListBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(ListBox1.Items.Item(arrayindex))

    Next arrayindex

    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM wk6"
    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\helse_000\Desktop\APU\VB Advanced\week4\ENTD461_wk4_Andrew_Helsel\ENTD461_wk2_Andrew_Helsel\calculator.mdb"
    Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
    Dim var1 As String = Convert.ToString(ListBox1.Items.Item(0))
    command.CommandText = "INSERT into wk6 (numFirst) VALUES (" + var1 + ")"
```

Comment: What does 'not working' mean??

Comment: It doesn't add anything to the Access database

Comment: Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961951/inserting-ms-access-row-into-database-using-vb-net

Comment: What have you done to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, removed the select all query string and made my textbox fields into parameters after modifying their results a bit to fit the format I needed for the table.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim firstString As String = Convert.ToString(ListBox1.Items.Item(i))
        Dim leftPart As String = firstString.Split(Convert.ToChar     
(strButtonSelected))(0)
        Dim rightPart As String = firstString.Split(Convert.ToChar("="))(1)
        Dim a As Integer = firstString.IndexOf(strButtonSelected)
        Dim b As Integer = firstString.IndexOf("=")
        Dim secNum = firstString.Substring(a + 1, b - 4)
        secNum = secNum.Trim

Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
Data Source=C:\Users\helse_000\Desktop\APU\VB Advanced\week4\ENTD461_wk4_Andrew_Helsel\ENTD461_wk2_Andrew_Helsel\calculator.mdb")

        Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
        Dim cmdstring As String = "INSERT INTO wk6 (numFirst, numSecond, Operator, equals, Answer)" + " VALUES (@firstName,@lastName,@Operator,@equals,@answer)"

        command = New OleDbCommand(cmdstring, conn)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", leftPart)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", secNum)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operator", strButtonSelected)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@equals", "=")
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", rightPart)
        conn.Open()

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        conn.Close()
```